# Why creating a function for Mysql I got syntax error?

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-function

In Dbeaver 22.2.5 I try to create a function for Mysql 8.0.21, which returns temp table, like

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getUserPermissionTickets$$
CREATE FUNCTION getUserPermissionTickets(permission_id INT, user_id INT)
RETURNS @resultTable TABLE (item varchar(255))
BEGIN
      insert  into @resultTable(item) values('Value')
END  $$
```

But I got errors :

> Error occurred during SQL query execution
> Reason:  SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@resultTable TABLE (item varchar(255))
> BEGIN
> insert  into @resultTable(it' at line 2

I see next : https://prnt.sc/QPvtSV7ZpsIS

How to fix it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: MYSQL does not have table variables or table value functions..step back a bit and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: `RETURNS {STRING|INTEGER|REAL|DECIMAL}` these are all that is allowed

Comment: Also, what are you expecting to return from a function that only does an INSERT

Comment: I guess you're trying to copy a definition from some other SQL dialect that allows returning tables from functions. Unfortunately, this isn't possible in MySQL.

Comment: I need to write Mysql 8 function/procedure which make union of data from several tables and return some result set(like custom table with given structure). Please reference to such example...